# Elegant way to convert string to dict and back

Tags: python, string, dictionary, type-conversion

Is there an elegant one-liner to convert this type of string to dict?
I googled now for an hour, but without several loops of splitting strings I can't get it to work.

```
Input  = "2:9, 6:90, 7:60"
Output = {'2': 9, '6': 90, '7': 60}
```

I would also need the reverse operation from dict to string.

Comment: Please provide more information on how this conversion would work. Why does an integer key suddenly become string?

Comment: `{key: int(val) for key, val in map(lambda x: x.strip().split(':'), Input.split(','))}` but it is so ugly that no one should use it. there is no shame using multiple lines to make such a transformation

Comment: for the fun, here is another ideous solution based on regex: `{key: int(val) for key, val in re.findall('(?P<key>\d+):(?P<val>\d+)', Input)}`

Comment: i'm not afraid of multiple lines. as a newbie I was more wondering if there's a more pythonian elegant way than multiple lines. happens too often, that I write lot of code with multiple loops etc and than I find out that there's a simple one-line solution in python :)
thx for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance wise most efficient will be normal `for` loop:

```
my_string = "2:9, 6:90, 7:60"
my_dict = {}
for s in my_string.split(', '):
     k, v = s.split(":")
     my_dict[k] = int(v)
```

where `my_dict` will contain:

```
>>> my_dict
{'2': 9, '7': 60, '6': 90}
```

---

To get back the same string, you can perform `.join()` on `dict.items()` as:

```
>>> ", ".join("{}:{}".format(k, v) for k, v in my_dict.items())
'2:9, 7:60, 6:90'
```

Or, you can also type-cast the dict to string and do some formatting on it like:

```
>>> str(my_dict)[1:-1].replace(": ", ":").replace("'", "")
'2:9, 7:60, 6:90'
```

Comment: thank you very much!
that for-loop is way more elegant than my multiple loop version :)
I def have to improve in pythons syntax. It's absolutely clear to me when I read your code, but I think I would have never figured this one out myself :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` and put brackets at each end of the string although your keys will be ints not strings.

```
from ast import literal_eval

Input  = "2:9, 6:90, 7:60"

Output = literal_eval(f"{{{input}}}")
```

---

```
{2: 9, 6: 90, 7: 60}
```

To fix the output to be string keys just convert them by hand

```
Output = dict(zip(map(str, Output), Output.values()))
```

---

```
{'2': 9, '7': 60, '6': 90}
```

---

**Without importing** any libraries you would need to use `str.split`

```
Output = dict(s.split(':') for s in Input.split(', '))
```

---

```
{'2': '9', '6': '90', '7': '60'}
```

Although now your values are strings so you'd need to fix that.

```
Output = dict(zip(Output, map(int, Output.values())))
```

---

```
{'2': 9, '7': 60, '6': 90}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well without asking questions, if you want a one liner that makes the key a string and the value an int:

```
dict([[j[0].strip(), int(j[1])] for j in [i.split(':') for i in Input.split(',')]])
```

Comment: this would be the perfect answer! I still go with Moinuddins answer as it is more readable for me being a newbie and has already the re-transformation. thx for your effort! it's highly appreciated!